# Number of Regressors in a Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling

I am building a model in R and want to perform some regressions (probably Poisson regression).

My problem is that I want to introduce about 330 dummy variables (entries only "1" and "0").

Is that possible and practical? If yes, could please advise me on how to that?

Any contribution is highly appreciated! 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. There is no theoretical limit to how many regressors you can use in your model, as long as it stays below the number of observations.

Nevertheless, if the number of variables gets close to the number of observations, parameter estimation will become increasingly difficult (you will get less precise estimations)

In response to the comments, I provide an example:

```r
data(mtcars) #Loads the mtcars dataset into a data.frame called mtcars
lm(mpg~., data=mtcars) #Creates a model for the target mpg, with all other columns in mtcars as predictors
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Thank you a lot! 

The number of variables is way less than the number of observations, so I suppose am fine.

Now, how could I implement it in R? How is it possible to incorporate so many variables in the model without writting them down ?

Comment: Yes. There is a trick! Put all the variables AND the target (let's call it ```y```) in a ```data.frame``` (let's call it ```train_data```). Just what you need in the model, no extras. Then add ```lm(y~. , data=train_data)``` This will fit a model to predict ```y``` using the rest of the variable in ```train_data```

Comment: Thank again! 

I tried it though but didn't work (probably because of me, since I am not experienced enough)! Could you please elaborate a bit more or write down those 2 lines of code? 

I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @CLBJ_23 Alright, I add that to the answer

Comment: I made it, thank you once more! 

Now, how could I make a prediction for that, since I cannot write each one of the independent variables? 

I know that I should use the command "predict()" to do that, though.

Comment: Just get a ```data.frame```with the same variables as the original one and use ```predict(model, newdata)```You can solve most doubts with ```?'predict'```